# Parsing text file (Python)

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text file with a bunch of lines which contains:

```
"blah0","blah1","blah2","blah3","blah4"
"blah5","blah6","blah7","blah8","blah9"
"blah10","blah11","blah12","blah13","blah14"
```

I have around 50 of these little guys, and I want the script to get rid of the stuff I don't need, all I would need is

```
blah2:blah3 blah7:blah8 blah12:blah13
```

and so on and so on.
How would I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've written part of it, I'm splitting the string after the second "," but this isn't working for the rest of the lines

Comment: And why not just open it in a spreadsheet program (it looks like a CSV file)? You can then delete the columns you don't want, search for and replace unwanted characters, and so on.

Comment: Didn't even think of that, I'll give that a go thank you :)

Comment: Python's standard lib has a `csv` module for reading this kind of data. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html and it will handle the quotes for you too.

Answer (score -1):

I cant tell how what information you really need, but using a spreadsheet editor is probably best. All you would need to do is remove the Quote marks, then your file is in csv format and can be opened in excel or most spreadsheet editors (rename to .csv).

To remove the quotes there are many options, like Find & Replace with any text editor (just enter nothing in replace).

You really dont need to program anything if you only have one of these files.